# Shortcut to 'fit system to view' in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

Using Simulink in Matlab R2010b, I can mark a couple of blocks and then click 'View -> fit System to view' and Simulink automatically zooms in on the marked blocks. I know there is a shortcut to do this, but I don't remember which one. Can anyone tell me?

Comment: Have you had a look at the [keyboard and mouse actions page](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/summary-of-mouse-and-keyboard-actions.html)?

Comment: @Johannes Yes, I have. Can you find it there? I can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hotkey you are looking for is f, it fits the selected blocks to the screen.
In more recent Simulink versions, this option is no longer available, the only alternative is spacebar which fits all blocks to the screen.

A list of all shortcuts is available in the [user guide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2010b/pdf_doc/simulink/sl_using.pdf) starting with page 1-43

Comment: No, it's not. When I mark a couple of blocks and then press space Simulink will zoom out to see the whole subsystem or model, but not zoom in on the selected blocks.

Comment: @Max I updated my answer, have mistaken the options because the function you are asking for is no longer present in Simulink. You can find it in the [documentation for your Simulink version](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2010b/pdf_doc/simulink/sl_using.pdf) on page 1-43

Comment: Yes, that's it, thank you! :) I already guessed, that this function has been removed since it's not listed the current documentation.